# Get a child value and set as the parent value using JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I have this input JSON:

```
{
  "stores": {
    "1100": {
      "metric1": "27",
      "metric2": "3013775",
      "indicator": 8.96
    },
    "1200": {
      "metric1": "2",
      "metric2": "354418",
      "indicator": 5.64
    }
  }
}
```

And need to transform the value of each *store* in the value from the child *indicator*, like that:

```
{
  "stores": {
    "1100": 8.96,
    "1200": 5.64
  }
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ***shift*** transformation like this

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "stores": {
        "*": {
          "indicator": "&2.&1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where **"*"** represents the indices of the **stores** object. eg we walk through the elements of the **stores** object as restricting results to the values of the **"indicator"** key in which **&2** represents going two level up and grabbing the key name(**"stores"**) and **&1** represents going one level up and grabbing the values of the indices(**"1100"**,**"1200"**)

[image]

Comment: It worked perfectly, thanks!